# PouchDb Error Property 'doc' does not exist on type '{ key: string; error: "not_found"; }'

Tags: angular, typescript, pouchdb

after updting some angular dependencies (15.1 to 15.2) (and possibly some transitive stuff downwards) I get errors in my pouchdb calls.

Simplified code:

```
// db is PouchDB.Database

const allDocs = await db.allDocs<Stuff>({
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: true,
    binary: true,
    keys: ['some', 'keys', 'from', 'somewhere', 'else']
});

console.log(allDocs.rows[0].doc._id);
```

Leads to an error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 
 '{ key: string; error: "not_found"; } | 
  { doc?: ExistingDocument<Photo & AllDocsMeta>; id: string; key: string; value: { rev: string; deleted?: boolean; }; }'.  
Property 'doc' does not exist on type '{ key: string; error: "not_found"; }'
```

This worked fine with the previous angular/dependency versions. Any idea what I'm missing?

---

Edit: I also tried the same stuff in a completly new project:

1. create project/dependencies

```
# install latest angular cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
# create a new project
ng new angular15-pouchdb
# add pouchdb
npm i pouchdb@7.3.1
# add types for pouchdb
npm i @types/pouchdb@6.4.0 --save-dev
```

2. tsconfig.json:

- add "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true to compilerOptions of tsconfig.json

3. create test code

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

class Stuff {
}

export class Foo {

  private async foo(db: PouchDB.Database) {
    const allDocs = await db.allDocs<Stuff>({
      include_docs: true,
      attachments: true,
      binary: true,
      keys: ['some', 'keys', 'from', 'somewhere', 'else']
    });

    console.log(allDocs.rows[0].doc._id);
  }
}
```

Results in same error.